# Nested Loop Optimisation in C and OpenMP

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

Actually I have two questions, the first one is, considering cache, which one of the following code is faster?

```
int a[10000][10000];
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
       a[i][j]++;
    }
}
```

or

```
int a[10000][10000];
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
       a[j][i]++;
    }
}
```

I am guessing the first one will be much faster since there are a lot less cache miss. And my question is if you are using OpenMP, what kind of technique will you use to optimise such a nested loop? My strategy is to divide the outer loop into 4 chunks and assign them among 4 cores, is there any better way (more cache friendly) to do it?

Thanks!
Bob

Comment: You can test both on you platform. But I assume, 1st fastest. Also, question: Is array element must be int? Perhaps, enough short or char? By decrease element size, you will decrease memory traffic.

Answer (score 2):

As maxihatop pointed out, the first one performs better because it has better cache locality.

Dividing the outer loop into chunks is a good strategy in the case like this, where the complexity of the task inside the loop is constant.

You might want to take a look at `#pragma omp for schedule(static)`. This will evenly divide the iterations contiguously among threads. So your code should look like:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
        a[i][j]++;
    }
```

Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory provides a fantastic tutorial of OpenMP. You can find more information there. 
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/